# python how to force subprocess.call to not wait for the called command to complete

Tags: python, subprocess

Im using subprocess.call to execute a bat file.  subprocess.call is waiting for the bat file to complete before it continues.  I want it to start the bat then continue on.  Looking at the documents for subprocess it didnt look like it had an option to not wait for the command to complete.

Is there a way to do this or another option besides subprocess.call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

subprocess.Popen is what you are looking for!